# Bootstrap 4 flexbox content 100% height

Tags: html, css, height, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I Have some problems with Bootstrap 4.

I Have activated flexbox and i want content in column to be 100% height.

This is the structure:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is the result:
[Flexbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhN30.jpg)

How can the gray background be 100% height? i tried with height: 100%. But the container will be 100% height of the page and not of the column. I also tried to set parent to relative and child to absolute. Doesn't worked.
Background color is set on content.

Codeexample:
http://jsfiddle.net/KjGZw/339/

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the `.col` divs flex-containers with `display:flex` and apply `flex-direction:column` to those.

Then set the `.content` divs to `flex:1`

```css
.row {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col {
  padding: 15px;
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  flex: 1;
}
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="content">
      Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="content">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="content">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="content">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="content">
      Test
      <br>Test
      <br>Test
      <br>Test
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="content">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```